# using created Visualize Kibana for other index patterns (same data)?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I'm having a problem with using Visualize Kibana. At first I make some Visualize and saved them, then I made another index pattern with the same data but with another name index. So how can I use my old Visualize for my new index pattern?
Thanks all.

Comment: Please specify the version of Kibana you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of Kibana you may be able to do it form Management->Saved Objects, here you can manage all your saved objects:

- open in Management the new index pattern you want to get in the visualization
- get the UUID of the index pattern from the address bar in the browser
- open the saved visualization (Management -> Saved Objects) and edit the kibanaSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON parameter with the UUID of the index pattern you want
- now the visualization will point to the new index

WARNING: with this method you can corrupt your saved objects and then you cannot recover them.

Comment: thanks a lots, I tried and successful. But i have some question? this way is the official way for my problem? And your WARNING is from the producer or just with your experience. Thanks again.

Comment: This is how i do it since a couple years when i have to make a quick change on some not so important visualization, it is also suggested in the official elastic forums. The warning is because messing with saved objects is in general dangerous, since there is no default backup mechanism or history. I usually to prefer make a new visualization since it is not so time consuming and less prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, it seems to be an issue with no practical solution.

There is a new type of visualization called Lens, which allows to change the index from the one originally saved. Just enter to edit the visualization, and you will find the name of the current index in the leftmost column, and will be able to change it.

A downside is that Lens has not yet all types of graphics (for example heat maps), but will work for bars, lines and sectors.